# C cannot endors another user permissions using setresuid

Tags: c, linux, setuid

I wrote the following code expecting to spawn a /bin/sh from another user.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
        setresgid(getegid(), getegid(), getegid());
        setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid());

        execve("/bin/sh", argv,  envp);
        return 0;
}
```

I then changed the owner to match with my target user and changed permissions (too much, I know)

```
chown usertarget:globalgroup ./shell
chmod 777 ./shell
chmod +s ./shell
```

[ls -lah shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ4q3.png)

Everything is fine according to me. However, It keeps opening a shell as my current user, not the target one.

I already tried to hardcode the userid of my target user and a few other things (setuid function, ...) but nothing seems to work...

Anyone has an idea or anything that could help me investigate this problem ?

EDIT #1

```
baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$ ls -lah shell2
-rwsrwsrwx 1 targetuser globalgroup 7.2K Aug 18 18:21 shell2

baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$ id
uid=1507(baseuser) gid=1314(globalgroup) groups=1314(globalgroup),100(users)

baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$ ls -lah shell2
-rwsrwsrwx 1 targetuser globalgroup 7.2K Aug 18 18:21 shell2

baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$ ./shell2

====== WELCOME USER ======
baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$ id -a
uid=1507(baseuser) gid=1314(globalgroup) groups=1314(globalgroup),100(users)
baseuser@machine:/tmp/tata$
```

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Please copy/paste your shell output showing the file permission and the output of the `id -a` command after running `./shell`.

Comment: Well i dont know how to format code in comment, edit is in the thread

Answer (score 0):

Well in facts, the parition was mounted with nosuid option. This can be checked through `mount` command